# change screen brightness when autobrightness enabled

Tags: android, screen-brightness

The code below to change screen brightness is not working when **auto brightness** of device is enabled:

```
Window w = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = w.getAttributes();

lp.screenBrightness=0.09f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

How to change this code for working on auto brightness too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISCLAIMER:
This code is kind of 'hackish', and might not work on all android versions and all android phones, and might not be the best code practice. I claim no responsibility if your device explodes, or it starts raining etc. :)

That being said, you might want to disable autobrightness temporarily:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
```

And then re-enable it:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);
```

Comment: Thanks,your code is working.but only when i use one of those,(i.e: when i disable autobrightness, code for enable it again not working)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is worked perfect on Android0.

```
   private void setBrightness(Activity activity, int brightness) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = activity.getWindow().getAttributes();
            lp.screenBrightness = Float.valueOf(brightness) * (1f / 255f);
            activity.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
```

It can be considered the priority of window attributes is higher than autobrightness.

You can check this logic in PowerManagerService.java -> updateDisplayPowerStateLocked.